# NGXS - how to use one action handler on multiple streams

Tags: ngxs

I have several actions that run asynchronously, let say `VerifyEmail` and `changepassword`. I would like to show a loader when the action starts and hide it when the auction ends. I know I can do it for each action this way :

```
this.actions$
    .pipe( ofActionDispatched(VerifyEmail) )
    .subscribe( () => {
        this.showLoader();
    });
this.actions$
    .pipe( ofActionSuccessful(VerifyEmail) )
    .subscribe( () => {
        this.hideLoader();
    });
```

But it is two blocks for each async actions, I was wondering if there is a way to combine several actions into a single pipe? something like `ofActionDispatched([VerifyEmail, ChangePassword])` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can combine the operator for multiple actions like this:

```
ofActionDispatched(VerifyEmail, ChangePassword)
```

*Note that it is just addition arguments to the method not an array.*

As an alternative you could bind this loader to a `loading` prop somewhere in your state and update that from your respective `@Action` handlers before and after doing the async work:

```
@Action(VerifyEmail)
async verifyEmail(ctx, action){
    ctx.patchState({ loading: true });
    await someasyncWork();
    ctx.patchState({ loading: false });
}
```

Yet another option is to call this from the UI component before and on completion of the dispatch:

```
this.showloader();
this.store.dispatch(new VerifyEmail())
    .subscribe(() => this.hideLoader());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wonderful thank you, right the second option really good too !